# Omnisharp not making helm integrations available

Tags: helm, csharp-mode

As a c# coder and emacs user, I've been playing with omnisharp (https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-emacs). It mostly seems to be working - following the instructions on that page I got company integrated well.

However m-x doesn't find almost all of the helm integrations, omnisharp-helm-find-usages and the like. helm-imenu works, with all the functions from the local file listed.

A brief look at the source shows that the helm integrations are included under this conditional:

```
(when (require 'helm-grep nil 'noerror)
```

...using m-x, I can't find helm-grep. I have helm-grep-mode and helm-grep-help, but no individual helm-grep. I can't find a package called that on elpa or melpa either.

I thought maybe I need to require 'helm *before* omnisharp in my init.el, but the docs linked above don't actually ask me to require 'omnisharp, just to add the hook to csharp-mode.

Comment: Of course there's no `helm-grep`. It is the name of `helm-grep` module in Helm. You only have `helm-do-grep` command. When you install Helm, `helm-grep` is already installed.

Comment: ok, cool. so why can't omnisharp find it and add its helm integrations?

Comment: What's printed when you evaluate `(require 'helm-grep nil 'noerror)` individually? For me, it returned `helm-grep`.

Comment: yep that's what I get too.

Comment: Probably you need to require `helm` before Omnisharp. Try `(require 'helm-config)`. `helm-config` is the default configuration that comes with Helm. It is recommended by Helm maintainer to always load this module, so you don't have to manually load individual Helm components. However, it doesn't include `helm-grep`, so you might need to add another line `(require 'helm-grep)`. But based on the code in omnisharp.el, it should be able to get into the body of `when`. If this doesn't work, maybe you should open a Github issue.

Comment: Here is a [sample setting](https://github.com/nosami/omnisharp-demo/blob/master/init.el#L143) for Helm and Omnisharp, provided by [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OmniSharpMakingCrossplatformNETARealityAndAPleasure.aspx). It seems you need load Helm modules before loading Omnisharp, as I suggested above. Did it succeed?

Comment: I'm starting to think there's bigger issues here. I've got a ticket open with omnisharp (https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-emacs/issues/129) that may or may not resolve this too. Or this might be something different! Will keep things updated.